# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - don't update specific field?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a MySQL query to eiter insert, or update a record if it already exists.

Problem is, I don't want to update my `'created'` datetime field.

My event data:

```
$event = [
    'userId'        => $this->userId,
    'googleEventId' => $googleEventId,
    'isAppointment' => $isAppointment,
    'eventTitle'       => $title,
    'eventLocation'    => $location,
    'eventDescription' => $description,
    'eventStart'    => $start,
    'eventEnd'      => $end,
    'created'       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), // This field should be ignored when updating
    'updated'       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
];
```

I'm using this function to insert, or insert-update on duplicate key (`$update` parameter):

```
public function insert($table, $data, $update = 0)
{
    ksort($data);

    $fieldNames  = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
    $fieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($data));

    $updateOnDuplicate = '';

    if ($update)
    {
        $updateOnDuplicate = ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ';

        foreach ($data as $key=> $value) {
            $updateOnDuplicate .= "$key=:$key,";
        }
        $updateOnDuplicate = rtrim($updateOnDuplicate, ',');
    }

    $stmt = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($fieldNames) VALUES ($fieldValues) $updateOnDuplicate");

    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

I guess I need to detect the `'created'` field inside this function somehow.

Comment: get the information already stored and then put that value in as the updated value

Comment: What are the keys in the table where you are trying to insert, and INSERT statement you currently have?

Comment: unset($event[$created]) on update? how are you forcing your query .. we can't guess seeing only 1 array.. Show the how query

Comment: Sorry guys, see my edit for a insert/update function I use.

Comment: That should work, just skip the 'created' field when you are looping over the fields to be updated for ODKU ,e.g. `if ($key!='created') {  $updateOnDuplicate .= "$key=:$key,";}`

Comment: @Ashalynd Yep, I think I submitted this question too soon. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `if($key!='created'){}` statement is the solution,

```
public function insert($table, $data, $update = 0)
{
    ksort($data);

    $fieldNames  = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
    $fieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($data));

    $updateOnDuplicate = '';

    if ($update)
    {
        $updateOnDuplicate = ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ';

        foreach ($data as $key=> $value) {
            if($key!='created'){ // Here you can do what you want
            $updateOnDuplicate .= "$key=:$key,"; 
            } // Here you can do what you want
        }
        $updateOnDuplicate = rtrim($updateOnDuplicate, ',');
    }

    $stmt = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($fieldNames) VALUES ($fieldValues) $updateOnDuplicate");

    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

now, you can run this fix code. Good luck